# ViewPager using FragmentPagerAdapter remove invisible pages from memory

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, fragmentpageradapter

i am developing an application which has view pager that includes 5 different fragments. Each fragment has many views, animations and listeners so my app runs slower. When  i add only first second and third pages  there is no problem but after adding others performance problem starts.  I thought removing invisible pages from ViewPager but it couse problem with CirclePageIndicator. i want that only 3 pages that "current page", "previous page" and "next page"  will be on screen others gone.

Anyone has idea about solving performance issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting the OffScreenPageLimit of your ViewPager to 1: `viewpager.setoffscreenpagelimit(1);`

Comment: hi Nickolaus, thanks for your answer. When i scroll to new page then come back 'onCreateView()' called and this makes error for my code. Is it possible to save last view state of older fragment?

Comment: are you sure the error is coming from the onCreateView method and not from the getView method in your adapter?

Comment: In XML file I import Google Maps V2 at line 45.  Exception is `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class fragment `    This exception occurs when `super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);` called

Comment: this is because your are inflating the XML, that has already been inflated, make a null check